# Pandas code doesnt work when inside a For loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

### **EDIT**
It seem i had put two completely different codes in the post.
I have fixed the changes. Please help, the code works outside a for loop but not inside it.

Guyz i seem to have a very weird issue,

This script works exactly as expected

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

wb = 'data/KSA STRATEGY OPSI.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(wb)

df = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name = 'OPSI', header=18)
columns_list = list(df.columns)
r = re.compile("[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{2}-Q")
columns_list = list(filter(r.match, columns_list)) # Read Note below
columns_list.insert(0, "Item_code")
columns_list.insert(1, "Type")
```

However when i put it inside a for loop;

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

wb = 'data/KSA STRATEGY OPSI.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(wb)

testdf = pd.ExcelFile(wb)
for sheet in testdf.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name = 'OPSI', header=df.index[df.iloc[:,0]=='Upload Flag'].tolist()[0])
    columns_list = list(df.columns)
    r = re.compile("[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{2}-Q")
    columns_list = list(filter(r.match, columns_list)) # Read Note below
    columns_list.insert(0, "Item_code")
    columns_list.insert(1, "Type")
```

when i run this code i get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [85], line 16
     14 columns_list = list(df.columns)
     15 r = re.compile("[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{2}-Q")
---> 16 columns_list = list(filter(r.match, columns_list)) # Read Note below
     17 columns_list.insert(0, "Item_code")
     18 columns_list.insert(1, "Type")

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What am i missing, ive been pulling my hair out a whole day!
Please help

I accept Im no expert at python but i would expect if some code runs normally it should run the same with inside a for Loop.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
columns_list = list(map(lambda x: str(x), filter(r.search, df.columns)))
```

to:

```
columns_list = list(map(lambda x: str(x), filter(r.search, columns_list )))
```

because df.columns is pandas.core.indexes.base.Index not a list